# Region width not refreshing automatically after modifying Grid Pane to which the region width is bound - JavaFX

Tags: javafx, binding

I'm making a simple Java GUI app using JavaFX that has a Border Pane as the root node.
In the top section of the Border Pane, there is a Grid Pane with three columns (`top Grid Pane` from now on).
In the first column of the top Grid Pane, there is a Home Button, in the second column, there is an empty Region that only serves as `spacer` between the first and third column of the top Grid Pane, and in the third column, there is another GridPane (`right Grid Pane` from now on).
The right Grid Pane contains one Button (Log In Button) on start. However, when a user successfully logs into the app, two other Buttons and a Label are added to the right Grid Pane as part of the Log In Button click event.
The spacer `maxWidthProperty` and `minWidthProperty` are bound to the top Grid Pane (`tgp`) widthProperty and the right Grid Pane(`rgp`) widthProperty like this:

```
spacer.minWidthProperty().bind(tgp.widthProperty().subtract(80).subtract(rgp.widthProperty()).subtract(3));
spacer.maxWidthProperty().bind(tgp.widthProperty().subtract(80).subtract(rgp.widthProperty()).subtract(3));
```

which makes the right Grid Pane move nicely with its buttons staying on the right side of the scene when a user resizes the main stage.
However, a problem occurs when the user logs in and additional buttons are added to the right Grid Pane. The spacer somehow misses this change and its width stays the same, which makes the additional Buttons appear outside of the current stage width. The only way to refresh the spacer width is to interact with the stage somehow, by clicking minimize/maximize/restore or by clicking any button on the scene.
Is there a way to automatically refresh Region width after the nodes to which its width is bound to are modified? Or, is there a better approach to making a top Grid Pane with one button on the left and modifiable number of buttons (nodes) on the right?

**Edit:** Here is a demonstration of the problem with several screenshots stacked on one another:
[image]

Minimal reproducible example:

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

GridPane tgp = new GridPane();
tgp.minWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());
tgp.maxWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());
tgp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: WHITE; -fx-border-color: LIGHTGREY;");
tgp.setMinHeight(37);
tgp.setMaxHeight(37);
root.setTop(tgp);

Button homeButton = new Button("Home"));
homeButton.setMinHeight(35);
homeButton.setMaxHeight(35);
homeButton.setMinWidth(80);
homeButton.setMaxWidth(80);
tgp.add(homeButton, 0, 0);

GridPane rgp = new GridPane(); // Right Grid Pane - holds User related nodes
rgp.setHgap(5);
tgp.add(rgp, 2, 0);

Label unl = new Label("My Profile");
unl.setFont(new Font("Calibri", 15));
unl.setTextFill(Color.RED);
unl.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

Button wlButton = new Button("Watchlist");
wlButton.setMinHeight(35);
wlButton.setMaxHeight(35);
wlButton.setMinWidth(80);
wlButton.setMaxWidth(80);

Button cartButton = new Button("Cart");
cartButton.setMinHeight(35);
cartButton.setMaxHeight(35);
cartButton.setMinWidth(60);
cartButton.setMaxWidth(60);

Button logInOutButton = new Button("Log In");
logInOutButton.setMinHeight(35);
logInOutButton.setMaxHeight(35);
logInOutButton.setMinWidth(60);
logInOutButton.setMaxWidth(60);
rgp.add(logInOutButton, 3, 0);

logInOutButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    if (logInOutButton.getText().equals("Log In")) {
                        LogInStage lis = new LogInStage();
                        lis.initStage();

                        if (lis.username != null) {
                            logInOutButton.setText("Log Out");
                            rgp.add(unl, 0, 0);
                            rgp.add(wlButton, 1, 0);
                            rgp.add(cartButton, 2, 0);
                        }

                    } else if (logInOutButton.getText().equals("Log Out")) {
                        logInOutButton.setText("Log In");
                        rgp.getChildren().remove(unl);
                        rgp.getChildren().remove(wlButton);
                        rgp.getChildren().remove(cartButton);
                    }

                }
            });

Region spacer = new Region();
spacer.minWidthProperty().bind(tgp.widthProperty().subtract(80).subtract(rgp.widthProperty()).subtract(3));
spacer.maxWidthProperty().bind(tgp.widthProperty().subtract(80).subtract(rgp.widthProperty()).subtract(3));
tgp.add(spacer, 1, 0)
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Sorry, will post in edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a bad idea to use bindings, if you can avoid it. Any changes to the size constraints can lead to a new layout pass being scheduled, but during the layout pass they are assumed to be constant. If you now introduce a binding the following sequence of events could happen:

1. A layout pass is requested for the `GridPane`, setting a flag to indicate layout is required
2. A layout pass happens. During the layout pass the children are resized. This triggers an update of the constraints of the children with the bindings.
3. The flag is cleared, but the changes to the contraints already happened. The layout won't reflect this. The `GridPane` gets another reason to do a layout.

I don't know, how your scene is set up in detail, but I recommend using column constraints: Set the grow priorities for the outer ones to `SOMETIMES` and the one for the center to `ALWAYS`. If you require some spacing around the children, you could use `GridPane.setMargin` (or the padding of the `GridPane` itself, if you require the a distance to the edges for all children).

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button[] rightContent = new Button[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < rightContent.length; i++) {
        Button btn = new Button(Integer.toString(i));
        GridPane.setColumnIndex(btn, i);
        rightContent[i] = btn;
    }

    Button cycle = new Button("cycle");
    GridPane rgp = new GridPane(); // I would usually use a HBox here
    // don't grow larger than needed
    rgp.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

    // cycle though 0 to 3 buttons on the right
    cycle.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        int nextIndex = 0;

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if (nextIndex >= rightContent.length) {
                rgp.getChildren().clear();
                nextIndex = 0;
            } else {
                rgp.getChildren().add(rightContent[nextIndex]);
                nextIndex++;
            }

        }
    });

    ColumnConstraints sideConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
    sideConstraints.setHgrow(Priority.SOMETIMES);

    ColumnConstraints centerConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
    centerConstraints.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

    //prefer to grow the center part of the GridPane
    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    root.getColumnConstraints().addAll(sideConstraints, centerConstraints, sideConstraints);

    root.add(cycle, 0, 0);
    root.add(rgp, 2, 0);

    // add something to visualize the center part
    // you could simply leave this part out
    Region center = new Region();
    center.setStyle("-fx-border-radius: 10;-fx-border-width: 1;-fx-border-color:black;");
    root.add(center, 1, 0);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, the `center` region is not actually needed.